# Why is TCP port 563 opened?

Tags: networking, tcp

Can someone explain what service opens TCP port 563 and uses it?
I`m using Windows.

Comment: Are you using a newsreader or other Usenet type program like Newzbin (perhaps for downloading files)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TCP port 563 is commonly used, or at least *was* commonly used once, for NNTP (USENET news transfer) over SSL. Most likely, the reason it's open on your particular machine has nothing to do with that though, and you should actually check what's using the port on your specific machine. `netstat -abn -p tcp` (from a command prompt with elevated privileges) will probably tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Right! Using netsat is the most simple solution.

If you want to have more detailled informations on what's running in yoir PC I suggest you to use MS TechNet sysinternals tools such as TcpView, Process Explorer and so on...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027

Check also this list of TCP-Ip ports:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

:)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Network Monitor will show all open connections and the processes that opened them: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=4865